# How to hide next and prev button in v-pagination vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

How do I hide the prev and next buttons in `v-pagination` in Vuetify?

My code-

```
<v-pagination
  v-model="page"
  :length="pageCount"
  :total-visible="8"
  color="primary"
/>
```

Comment: Can you please tell us, why you need that? Because if you will hide those buttons then how'd you manage the back-and-forth navigation?

Comment: There is a prop to change next and previous icon. Just take a look at the documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-pagination/

Answer (score 0):

If the document has no hidden button attribute, you can try to overwrite css

```
v-deep
```

Answer (score 0):

if you really need it

```
.v-pagination > li:first-child,
.v-pagination > li:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```